# Change static element value through reflection with string as element name

Tags: java, reflection

I'm getting data from a DB and access through the field names of the class DBUserValues and want to save the results in a DBUserValues object. There is always only one result. How to I access these static variables with a string? Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class DBUserValues {
    public static String username;
    public static String firstname;
}
```

Go through results and save them

```
for (Field field : user.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    // Result should get saved in DBUserValues object
    // DBUserValues.username = result.getString(field.getName();
    // DBUserValues.(field.getName()) = result.getString(field.getName());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to have the fields declared as `static` in `DBUserValues` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) to map database fields with private attributes and public getters and setters:

```
class DBUserValues {
    // private attributes
    private String username;
    private String firstname;

    // public getters and setters
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
}
```

---

> How do I invoke now these getter and setter? `field.invoke("set" + field.getName(), result.getString(field.getName()))` does not work.

You must create a `DBUserValues` object to populate, also there is missing code, but I don't think you must iterate over `user.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` result:

```
// get database values
Field[] fields = user.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

// create an object to populate:
DBUserValues user = new DBUserValues();
user.setUserName(fields[0]);
user.serFirstName(fields[1]);
```

---

**ADD ON:** check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852950/cannot-use-getdeclaredfields-to-retrieve-fields-of-a-scala-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158830/java-reflection-accessing-fields-of-a-field) to know how to retrieve the correct info from `user.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`.

Comment: How do I invoke now these getter and setter? `field.invoke("set" + field.getName(), result.getString(field.getName()))` does not work

Comment: Thx for the replay. The problem is I don't want to do this, since this is a simplified version from the real DBUserValues Class. The real class has 13 fields and will change in the future, so I want do it in a way that allows easy changes of the DB.

Comment: what is the problem? you must populate your objects in some way, if you don't use hibernate to map your db and some populator like dozer you must perform manually the action... Sorry to say I don't think there's other way.

Comment: Okey if there is no better way I'll do it like that. Thx for the help. :)